# Java - how do you search through an array of strings to remove all the quotation marks?

Tags: java, string, quotations

Let's say, for example, I have an array of 5 elements, each of them being a string. One of the strings, however, has quotation marks around it, which I would like to remove automatically. Is there a function for doing this easily?

*remove the quotation marks, that is. Not the entire string from the array

Comment: Does any string have *embedded* " characters?

Answer (score 4):

Remove all quotes from a string:

```
String input = "foo \"bar\" baz";
String output = input.replace("\"", "");
```

http://ideone.com/RFZZq

Answer (score 3):

Because the `String` would be in array, you would have to loop through the entire array, and for each element, check to see if quotations marks were found. If they were found, they will be removed by using `String's` `replace` method. Example below:

```
String[] myArray = {"This", "may", "have", "a", "\"Quotation\"", "In", "It"};
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i].contains("\"")) {
      myArray[i] = myArray[i].replace("\"", "");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `String#replaceAll()` here (which treats the first parameter as a regular expression) and not `String#replace()`?

Comment: Thank you for questioning me on that, I went and researched a bit on Java's API and found `replaceAll` is best used for regex-related replacement, when `replace` is used for just simplistic string replacements.

Answer (score -3):

Above mentioned ways are good but you can also do that through this code

```
      String s1 = "bhb/vgvg/vvv";
      String fr[] = s1.split("/");

      for (String string : fr) 
      {
        System.out.print(string);
      }
```

It will also remove all the quotes from a string